# what is the correct command to search for an exact string ,

Tags: string, jython

i have tried startswith , find , re.sub but all seems to be find that string that matches part of it . iam looking for command which searchs the exact string which iam searching for in a given file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to give more detail on what you have tried and what you are wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing as to what you're asking about, but I *think* what you're wanting is to find an exact *line* of text in a file.  If that's the case, there are a couple of ways to do it.

Use a regex to match start and end of line:

```
regex = re.compile("^whatevermystringis$", re.M)
match = regex.search(open(filename).read())
match.span()
```

Find the line using straight Python:

```
line_to_find = "blah, blah, blah\n"
for line_num, line in enumerate(open(filename)):
    if line == line_to_find:
        print line_num
```

(Take care in handling your line endings.)

Again, this is a guess as to what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Is double quotation mandotary can we use single quote for string match as i have line which have double quotes and string inside it and i want to use that in the string search

Comment: Did I guess correctly on what you were wanting to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your help retracile. Iam sort of new to Jython and learning to write some added functionality for an Oracle Tool.

I have a string some what like this <Field name="TableName" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[SALES_PERSON]]></Field> 
so what i actually wanted to do is when i find  one part of the above string till - sales person i wish to replace with [above_string + trim ( ] and  (  ]]></Field>  ) with   )]]></Field> ie. adding an close bracket inshort making the final string to replace as <Field name="TableName" type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[ TRIM(SALES_PERSON)]]></Field>

Comment: If you're still having trouble with that, I would recommend asking another question.